# heroku Java oAuth with Salesforce

Tags: java, heroku, oauth, salesforce

I have to create a security layer on top of my current Heroku app/salesforce connection using OAuth 2. It has to be that the authorization server and resource server is on the Heroku side so others cannot access the Heroku. The Heroku is effectively being sent some data through a Salesforce callout and then returning the computed results. I have found numerous tutorials from Salesforce as the server side but I cannot find any with a Java based Heroku. I have also found the apache oltu library but cannot find any tutorials as to how to use it correctly. If anyone could give me any tips/tutorials/code snippets, would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help: https://www.jamesward.com/2016/01/26/quick-force-java-getting-started-with-salesforce-rest-in-java

Code is at: https://github.com/jamesward/quick-force-java

It has the OAuth pieces and runs on Heroku.

Comment: Hi James, thanks a lot for the reply but I have a few issues with your code. Firstly, take note that I have less than a couple weeks experience with Java and no Scala experience. Further to your guidance, I want the page to simply authorize then run my own code rather than get the accounts page on your implementation (my heroku doesnt display data, it only computes data). How would you suggest I edit your code to suit this. I see on line 45-47 the get accounts section, how would I alter this to run some Java code instead and send the result as a response. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoshWindsor If you are doing a machine-to-machine integration then you won't use the typical OAuth web flow to get a token.  Instead you will use a password flow.  More info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm

Comment: Once again, I really appreciate the help. Are you sure this would be the best approach, I have read that this is a less secure implementation (security is key point here) and  one of my requirements is the Admin being able to revoke access. I fully understand the theory behind the OAuth flows at this point, but I'm still having a very hard time grasping the actual code side of this. Do you have any recommended pure Java libraries I could use for this and/or any tutorials/snippets to look at. Thanks again!

Comment: You could manually get an access token and refresh token then use those instead of a password.  But I don't know if that is necessarily more secure.  I'm not aware of any well maintained Java REST API wrappers for Salesforce.  Might exist but it seems like the Node.js libs are the most maintained at this point.

Comment: On another note there might be other ways to do the machine-to-machine integration you are trying to achieve.  For instance I've found that Salesforce Connect / External Objects are a great way to get external data into Salesforce.  Heroku Connect can be a great way to do integrations that need to sync data between Salesforce and a Postgres DB.  And to get change events out of Salesforce you can use Workflow: https://www.jamesward.com/2016/08/10/quick-easy-etl-from-salesforce-to-mysql-with-workflow-heroku/  Between those tools, I rarely need to do manual integrations.

Comment: As my Js skills (never used node however) are a lot better than my Java, I'm going to translate my app into Node.js and try follow some oAuth libraries over there. I'm not using any Heroku DB's so I think this is probably the best course of action. Thanks for all the help, if there is any Node.js tutorials you would recommend or anything else please let me know. Thanks again

Comment: I have a similar sample app for Node: https://github.com/jamesward/quick-force-node

Comment: Further to this discussion and after a day of messing about. I have decided to scrap the Salesforce authentication and instead authenticate with heroku from salesforce in a standard flow as doing it this way requires the additional query and for me to create a temporary object instead of simply sending the info across!